# Using variables in SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

I want to run the following SELECT query:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(50)
SET @ColumnName = 'AlarmID' -- actually these are calculated 
                            -- by another SELECT but this isn't relevant
SELECT MIN(@ColumnName) FROM INSERTED
```

This doesn't work, it returns the value of @ColumnName instead of the actual data.  How can I make this work?

I cannot put the SELECT into a string and run it with sp_executesql because I will lose access to the INSERTED table (this is running in a trigger).

Comment: what is the value returned by `@ColumnName` and your expected result?

Comment: In the above example, the value the select returns is 'AlarmID', I was expecting an int as the AlarmID column in the INSERTED table is an int.

Comment: maybe you can add sample records with desired result and the *unrelevant* sql query.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942082/how-to-pass-column-name-with-parameter-in-insert-sql-statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EXEC('SELECT MIN(' + @ColumnName + ') FROM INSERTED')
```

Derived from [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure) smoore provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want the minimum as a variable:

```
SELECT @columnName = MIN(@ColumnName) FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that.  Your best bet, depending on number of possible values of @ColumnName, is to dynamically set the field value with a case statement, or selectively run the right query using an IF statement:

```
SELECT CASE @ColumnName WHEN 'AlarmID' THEN MIN(AlarmID) WHEN 'AnotherField' THEN
MIN(AnotherField) END AS MinimumValue FROM INSERTED
```

OR

```
IF @ColumnName = 'AlarmID'
  SELECT MIN(AlarmID) FROM INSERTED
ELSE
  ....
```